Horizontal alignment of listings in subfigures
I would like to put two listings next to each other in two subfigures. In the below example, the 4cm \rules and the frame=single on the listings are just to illustrate where I believe the two listings should be vs. where they are.
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \centering
    \rule{4cm}{0.5em}
    \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single, autogobble, linewidth=4cm]
       . 2 . | 9 . 8 | . . .
       8 7 . | . . 1 | . 5 4
       5 . 6 | 4 . . | . 1 .
       ------+-------+------
       . . 2 | . . . | . 9 5
       . . . | . . . | . . .
       9 4 . | . . . | 8 . .
       ------+-------+------
       . 8 . | . . 4 | 5 . 3
       1 3 . | 2 . . | . 8 6
       . . . | 3 . 7 | . 2 .
    \end{lstlisting}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \centering
    \rule{4cm}{0.5em}
     \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single, autogobble, linewidth=4cm]
       4 2 1  9 5 8  6 3 7
       8 7 3  6 2 1  9 5 4
       5 9 6  4 7 3  2 1 8
       
       3 1 2  8 4 6  7 9 5
       7 6 8  5 1 9  3 4 2
       9 4 5  7 3 2  8 6 1
       
       2 8 9  1 6 4  5 7 3
       1 3 7  2 9 5  4 8 6
       6 5 4  3 8 7  1 2 9
     \end{lstlisting}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Example input and output over serial}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

In the below screenshot, I've marked with green where I expected the listings to be (and where I want them to be!). Also note the edges of the paper on the screenshot.


Set the width of the subfigure to be the same at the width of the lstlisting (4cm), and add \hfil between them.  Note that a subfigure is just a minipage with captions, which you aren't using.

You could use minipages to centre the listings:
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \centering
    \rule{4cm}{0.5em}
    
    \begin{minipage}{4cm}
    \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single, autogobble]
       . 2 . | 9 . 8 | . . .
       8 7 . | . . 1 | . 5 4
       5 . 6 | 4 . . | . 1 .
       ------+-------+------
       . . 2 | . . . | . 9 5
       . . . | . . . | . . .
       9 4 . | . . . | 8 . .
       ------+-------+------
       . 8 . | . . 4 | 5 . 3
       1 3 . | 2 . . | . 8 6
       . . . | 3 . 7 | . 2 .
    \end{lstlisting}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \centering
    \rule{4cm}{0.5em}
    
    \begin{minipage}{4cm}
     \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single, autogobble]
       4 2 1  9 5 8  6 3 7
       8 7 3  6 2 1  9 5 4
       5 9 6  4 7 3  2 1 8
       
       3 1 2  8 4 6  7 9 5
       7 6 8  5 1 9  3 4 2
       9 4 5  7 3 2  8 6 1
       
       2 8 9  1 6 4  5 7 3
       1 3 7  2 9 5  4 8 6
       6 5 4  3 8 7  1 2 9
     \end{lstlisting}
   \end{minipage}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Example input and output over serial}
\end{figure}
\end{document}


